# xbar, last keyword and subtract from table column

Tags: kdb

```
a:([]time:(2021.01.31D22:18:00.000000000;2021.01.31D22:18:27.134000000;2021.01.31D22:18:27.834000000;2021.01.31D22:21:14.284000000);val:(3.2;2.9;3.9;6.8))

time                          val
---------------------------------
2021.01.31D22:18:00.000000000 3.2
2021.01.31D22:18:27.134000000 2.9
2021.01.31D22:18:27.834000000 3.9
2021.01.31D22:21:14.284000000 6.8

a1:select last val by 0D00:01 xbar time from a
time                         | val
-----------------------------| ---
2021.01.31D22:18:00.000000000| 3.9
2021.01.31D22:21:00.000000000| 6.8

a2:update diff:val - last val by 0D00:01 xbar time from a

time                          val diff
--------------------------------------
2021.01.31D22:18:00.000000000 3.2 -0.7
2021.01.31D22:18:27.134000000 2.9 -1  
2021.01.31D22:18:27.834000000 3.9 0   
2021.01.31D22:21:14.284000000 6.8 0
```

for the 2nd, 3rd rows in a2, when there are no matching time values in a1, how does q query work to ensure that the val column is subtracted against the "last" val corresponding to the minute? is there a general rule to understand the use of xbar here or any reference for similar examples I could read?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This alternative approach should help you with understanding how the grouping by xbar is working:

```
q)ungroup{update diff:val-last val from x}each`grouper xgroup update grouper:0D00:01 xbar time from a
grouper                       time                          val diff
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2021.01.31D22:18:00.000000000 2021.01.31D22:18:00.000000000 3.2 -0.7
2021.01.31D22:18:00.000000000 2021.01.31D22:18:27.134000000 2.9 -1
2021.01.31D22:18:00.000000000 2021.01.31D22:18:27.834000000 3.9 0
2021.01.31D22:21:00.000000000 2021.01.31D22:21:14.284000000 6.8 0
```